# Convert []float64 pixel slice to an Image

Tags: image, go, rgb, grayscale

I'm attempting to resize and convert an image into a grayscale slice of float64 (so I can do some transformations on the floats) and then back into an image, but I'm not sure how to convert a []float64 back to RGB or something I can turn into an image.

So far I have:

```
// colorToGrayScaleFloat64 reduces rgb
// to a grayscale approximation.
func colorToGrayScaleFloat64(c color.Color) float64 {
    r, g, b, _ := c.RGBA()
    return 0.299*float64(r) +
        0.587*float64(g) +
        0.114*float64(b)
}

func getFloatPixels(filePath string) {
    size := 32
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("FAILED TO OPEN FILE: %s", err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close()

    image, _, err := image.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("FAILED TO DECODE FILE: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // Resize image to 32X32
    im := imaging.Resize(image, size, size, imaging.Lanczos)

    // Convert image to grayscale float array
    vals := make([]float64, size*size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < size; j++ {
            vals[size*i+j] = colorToGrayScaleFloat64(im.At(i, j))
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("pixel vals %+v\n", vals)
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
pixel vals [40315.076 48372.797 48812.780999999995 47005.557 ... 25129.973999999995 24719.287999999997]
```

How can I convert this pixel []float64 back to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have the luminosity of the gray pixel, and you want to have a [`color.Color`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Color) value representing it.

This is quite simple: there is a [`color.Gray`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Gray) type, and a higher precision [`color.Gray16`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Gray16) which model the color with its luminosity, so simply create a value of those. They implement `color.Color`, so you can use them to set pixels of an image.

```
col := color.Gray{uint8(lum / 256)}
```

Also note that your `colorToGrayScaleFloat64()` function is already present in the standard lib. There are several converters in the [`image/color`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color) package as implementations of [`color.Model`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Model). Use the `color.GrayModel` or `color.Gray16Model` to convert a `color.Color` to a value of type `color.Gray` or `color.Gray16` which directly store the luminosity of the gray color.

For example:

```
gray := color.Gray16Model.Convert(img.At(x, y))
lum := float64(gray.(color.Gray16).Y)
```

Testing it:

```
c := color.RGBA{111, 111, 111, 255}
fmt.Println("original:", c)

gray := color.Gray16Model.Convert(c)
lum := float64(gray.(color.Gray16).Y)
fmt.Println("lum:", lum)

col := color.Gray{uint8(lum / 256)}

r, g, b, a := col.RGBA()
a >>= 8
fmt.Println("lum to col:", r/a, g/a, b/a, a)
fmt.Println()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yGBWmvm8Tkn)):

```
original: {111 111 111 255}
lum: 28527
lum to col: 111 111 111 255
```

Also note that if you want to create an image full of gray pixels, you may use the [`image.Gray`](https://pkg.go.dev/image#Gray) and [`image.Gray16`](https://pkg.go.dev/image#Gray16) types so when drawing these colors on them, no color conversion will be needed. They also have designated [`Gray.SetGray()`](https://pkg.go.dev/image#Gray.SetGray) and [`Gray16.SetGray16()`](https://pkg.go.dev/image#Gray16.SetGray16) methods that directly take colors of these types.

See related:

[Converting RGBA image to Grayscale Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516203/converting-rgba-image-to-grayscale-golang/42518487#42518487)